# Couldn't inject DbContext in generic data access layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I have generic data access layer implemented with interfaces without a `DbContext` class; this is the code

```
public interface IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter, int page, int pageSize, string[] includePaths = null, params SortExpression<T>[] sortExpressions);

}
```

This is the concrete implementation:

```
public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> 
    where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<DbContext> _contextFactory;

    public GenericDataRepository(Func<DbContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public virtual IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter, int page, int pageSize, string[] includePaths = null, params SortExpression<T>[] sortExpressions)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = _contextFactory())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            list = dbQuery.ToList<T>();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

**Important:** the concrete class takes a `DbContext` param because this generic repository will be called from different modules, and they have thier own `DbContext`.

Now I am calling this repository from some other layer with this code

```
public interface IBusinessLayer
{
    void AddCountries(params Country[] Countries);
}

public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    Func<AccountingDBContext> _dbcontext;
    public void AddCountries(params Country[] Countries)
    {

        var repository = new GenericDataRepository<Country>(_dbcontext);
        //repository.Add(Countries);
    }
}
```

My problem arise from where I am calling this repository (above code).

The error is that `_dbcontext` is never assigned.  I think there is some issue in `Func<AccountingDBContext> _dbcontext;`.

Comment: Are you talking about dependency injection?  If so, what framework and how are you registering the context / context factory?  Of course `_dbcontext` is null - it's never assigned.  Typically with DI you'd assign it via the constructor of `BusinessLayer`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes may be i am talking about dependency injection, but i dont know how to implement that , i assume we can pass db context to different modules to perform task for passed dbcontext , my core objective is to create generic data access layer that perform CRUD operations for all the modules in my project (like payroll, sales) etc . i created different projects for each module with thier own db context . if u know such architecture so let me know or give me link

Comment: Start here (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/getting-started/) and then come back with questions.  Your factory is probably not required.  You'd just inject the applicable `IGenericDataRepository<T>` into the business layer and go from there.  [autofac reference added only cause I used it recently.  Any framework will do]

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks sir my problem is solved , now i have other issue with this link [ new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849426/couldnt-apply-case-insensitivity-in-generic-expression-builder)