# Couldn't apply case insensitivity in generic expression builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have a generic expression builder with following code:

```
 public class EntityExpression
{
    public enum Op
    {
        Equals,
        GreaterThan,
        LessThan,
        GreaterThanOrEqual,
        LessThanOrEqual,
        Contains,
        StartsWith,
        EndsWith,
        Nothing,
            StringEquals
    }
    public class Filter
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public Op Operation { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public static Op Operatorstranslation(string InputOperator)
        {
            switch (InputOperator)
            {
                case "eq":
                    return Op.Equals;
                case "startswith":
                    return Op.StartsWith;
                case "contains":
                    return Op.Contains;
            }
            return Op.Nothing;

        }

    }
    public static class ExpressionBuilder
    {
        private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains" );
        private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo compareMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Compare", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
        {
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
            else if (filters.Count == 2)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
            else
            {
                while (filters.Count > 0)
                {
                    var f1 = filters[0];
                    var f2 = filters[1];

                    if (exp == null)
                        exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
                    else
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]));

                    filters.Remove(f1);
                    filters.Remove(f2);

                    if (filters.Count == 1)
                    {
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));
                        filters.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
        }

        private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
          //  ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);


            var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

            if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))) // 2
                throw new NotSupportedException();


            var propertyValue = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(filter.Value.ToString());
            var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
            var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType);


            ConstantExpression stringComparisonConstant = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);



            switch (filter.Operation)
            {
                case Op.Equals:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, valueExpression);

                case Op.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, valueExpression);

                case Op.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, valueExpression);

                case Op.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, valueExpression);

                case Op.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, valueExpression);



                      case Op.Contains:

                    return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, valueExpression);


                case Op.StringEquals:
                    var zeroConstant = Expression.Constant(0);
                    var compareExpression = Expression.Call(compareMethod, member, valueExpression, stringComparisonConstant);
                    return Expression.Equal(compareExpression, zeroConstant);



                case Op.StartsWith:
                            return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, valueExpression);

                        case Op.EndsWith:
                            return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, valueExpression);


            }

            return null;
        }

        private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>
        (ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter filter2)
        {
            Expression bin1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
            Expression bin2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);

            return Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
        }
    }


}
```

my problem is this code wont works with case insensitivity especially with `containsMethod`, obviously because there is no case free code in that operation, but `compareMethod` works perfectly with any case because of proper code for case insensitivity.

I want to my `containsMethod` to works with any case (upper or lower). Can any one help me in this code?

Comment: this code is modified from this sample [Sample Code Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq?fid=1831241&df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=False&view=Normal&fr=101#xx0xx)    some one asked with the author about case insensitivity issue but not for containsMethod

Comment: Implement your own contains method using this technique? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx